# "at + noun" without article between

Tags: articles, zero-article

Consider these

> that's what I learned **at school**
>
> that's the major I learned **at University**
>
> she works **at home**
>
> How many people are working **at Microsoft**

In those examples "at school", "at home", "at University", there is no article between "at" and "noun".

What are the rules for that? one of them is "at + [proper noun](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-proper.htm)", what else?

Comment: I think we have to memorize such phrases. Although there might be some explanations for other usages of the articles, such sort-of-fixed phrases should be memorized.

Answer (score 1):

No article is used before 'home' in general sense. But "At the home" is something different. There must have been a specific home you have talked about earlier.

The definite article *'the'* isn't  used before the places such as 'university'/'college', 'prison'/'jail', 'hospital', and church, when we think of these places in general terms :

> e.g., *"That's what I learned **at school**."*

However, you may use the definite article *'the'* when you have a context that may clarify the use of the article :

> e.g., *"I had studied at St. Stephen's School, and that's what I learned **at the school**.*

Similarly, the same grammatical rules apply to others.

Answer (score 0):

This has little to do with the preposition **at** and more to do with the way the nouns are being used.

A noun like **school** can be used two different ways:

1. As a *concrete noun* referring to a physical building (or complex of buildings) in the real world. "The father went to **the school** to meet his daughter's teacher."
2. As an *abstract noun* referring to the general concept or activity of primary learning. "Most American children go to **school** for twelve years."

Abstract nouns use no article, whether they are in a prepositional phrase or not:

- **School** was difficult for him.
- She spends most of her day **at school**.
- Hurry up or you'll be late **for school**.

Concrete nouns do use an article, whether they are in a prepositional phrase or not:

- **A school** is being built downtown.
- **The school** is on fire!
- I will meet you later **behind the school**.

Proper names, as you note, also do not use articles:

- **Microsoft** released three new products today.
- I got a job **at Microsoft**.

Note that **home** is always an abstract noun, except in the meaning of a convalescent or retirement home. A **house** or an **apartment** is a concrete place, but **home** is the abstract concept of place being a primary residence.